# Blazor WebAssembly Monitor Threading exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, blazor, webassembly, .net-standard-2.1

I'm currently working on a **.NET Standard 2.1 Blazor WebAssembly** hosted application.

My application structure looks like this:

- BlazorApp.Client (error occures here)
- BlazorApp.Server

I use Serilog with the Elasticsearch sink in my BlazorApp.Client project. It works fine, but when I enable `Selflog` on Serilog and debug, I get the following error in my browser console:

```
SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
```

**Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime. ---> System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException: Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime.**

**at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.Monitor.Monitor_wait(object,int)**

**at System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait (System.Boolean exitContext, System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Object obj) <0x36c60c8 + 0x00046> in :0**

**at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (System.Object obj, System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Boolean exitContext) <0x36c5de8 + 0x00022> in :0**

It seems to be an issue in the current Blazor WASm release: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22400

`Cannot Wait on monitors` Does anyone know, how to possibly get rid of this error in Blazor WebAssembly Client?

Comment: I think the current MONO runtime on WASM only supports a single thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot 'get rid of' that error in Blazor WebAssembly. WebAssembly code is (for the time being) single-threaded so executing `System.Threading.Monitor.Wait(something);` would be a guaranteed deadlock.

The framework correctly signals to you that this code is not suitable for WebAssembly.

You will have to get rid of of any code that needs to Wait().